# Google oauth2 get id_token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am working in client side angularjs.I am try to implement google oauth2. I am getting accesstoken but i need to get id_token.

I added app.js , controller.js and html part.

I followed this tutorial: http://anandsekar.github.io/oauth2-with-angularjs/

app.js:

```
 angular
  .module('angularoauthexampleApp', [ ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/access_token=:accessToken', {
        template: '',
        controller: function ($location,$rootScope) {
          var hash = $location.path().substr(1);

          var splitted = hash.split('&');
          var params = {};

          for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
            var param  = splitted[i].split('=');
            var key    = param[0];
            var value  = param[1];
            params[key] = value;
            $rootScope.accesstoken=params;
          }
          $location.path("/about");
        }
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('angularoauthexampleApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.login=function() {
        var client_id="your client_id";
        var scope="email";
        var redirect_uri="http://localhost:9000";
        var response_type="token";
        var url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope="+scope+"&client_id="+client_id+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+
        "&response_type="+response_type;
        window.location.replace(url);
    };
  });
```

html:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **nonce**. Add it and **id_token** will be in response.

For example:

```
let params = {
    'client_id': GOOGLE_API_CLIEND_ID,
    'redirect_uri': `${location.origin}/auth/google`,
    'response_type': 'id_token token',
    'scope': GOOGLE_API_SCOPES,
    'state': 'af0ifjsldkj',
    'nonce': 'n-0S6_WzA2Mj'
};
```

For *implicit flow* **nonce** param is required. For more information you can check http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitAuthRequest

Comment: One more thing - without nonce your id_token in response type will not work and it looks like google security side effect, not for per spec

Answer (score 2):

To receive an **id_token**, you need to change your **response_type** param to:

```
var response_type="id_token";
```

as the response you will get an **id_token**. If you need both - the **id_token** and **access_token**, you should add "*token*" to **response_type**:

```
var response_type="token id_token";
```

To learn more, [read OpenId article](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect)

Also you could test auth flow using [Google Ouath Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

Answer (score 0):

To trigger an OpenID Connect flow, which is an extension of OAuth 2.0, you need to add the "openid" scope in the authentication request (and urlencode the space in between), so:

```
var scope="openid%20email";
```

Comment: I tried but i am getting  like this :  "ya29.CjQLA2yjm5drVlAPKU_aKCEFeeMM_Ikezqw7rOe9y2PzUDUdsJSt5A5m1D_sjpOCcryMSmuj"
authuser :"2",
expires_in:"3600"
hd:"xxx.com"
prompt:"none"
session_state:"bb554bedabf47c6f54aa07d0c69ba383b9ef23a6..1c93"
token_type:"Bearer"

Comment: I didn;t get the id_token